# Foreach loop returning only last result

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I need to format a YYYY-MM-DD date to output like "12 January 2020", I have got the date to output correctly, but the code will only output one of the five values that I want, I've obviously missed something.

I'm having an issue where the following code only outputs a single result:

```
function populate_dropdown($form){

    //Reading posts for "Events" post type;
    $posts = get_posts("post_type=el_events&orderby=date&order=asc&el_eventcategory=flo-talanoa&numberposts=-1");

    //Creating drop down item array.
    $items = array();
    //Adding post dates titles to the items array
    foreach($posts as $post)
        $unformatteddate = $post->startdate;
        $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $unformatteddate);
        $dateformatted = $dateTime->format('j F Y');
        $items[] = array(
            "value" =>  $dateformatted . ': ' . $post->location, 
            "text" => $dateformatted . ': ' . $post->location
        );

    //Adding items to field id 1.
    foreach($form["fields"] as &$field)
        if($field["id"] == 1){
            $field["type"] = "select";
            $field["choices"] = $items;
        }

    return $form;
}
```

If I replace:

```
            $unformatteddate = $post->startdate;
            $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $unformatteddate);
            $dateformatted = $dateTime->format('j F Y');
            $items[] = array(
                "value" =>  $dateformatted . ': ' . $post->location, 
                "text" => $dateformatted . ': ' . $post->location
            );
```

With:

```
$items[] = array("value" => $post->startdate . ': ' . $post->location, "text" => $post->startdate . ': ' . $post->location);
```

The code outputs all five values (though with YYYY-MM-DD date format), what am I missing? I'm a novice when it comes to PHP.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `{}` in your `foreach` loop

```
foreach($posts as $post){
    $unformatteddate = $post->startdate;
    $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $unformatteddate);
    $dateformatted = $dateTime->format('j F Y');
    $items[] = array(
        "value" =>  $dateformatted . ': ' . $post->location, 
        "text" => $dateformatted . ': ' . $post->location
    );
}

//Adding items to field id 1.
foreach($form["fields"] as &$field){
    if($field["id"] == 1){
        $field["type"] = "select";
        $field["choices"] = $items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the curly braces {} in foreach.